# How can i print a list object and get a list without ' '?

Tags: python-3.x, list, object

I mean, if I have the list objects ['hello' , 'how', 'are', 'you'] and I want to convert to [hello, how, are, you].
Thanks!

Comment: You have a list of `string` objects and you want to convert it to a list of ...... ?

Comment: By definition, a string is surrounded by `"` or `'`. If you remove the quotation marks, python understand it is a variable. A variable has a content. You can find an introduction on type [here](http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch03.html)

Comment: strings needs `'` without it it's just variables which are not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print it you can do:

```
a = ['hello' , 'how', 'are', 'you']
print(f'[{", ".join(a)}]')

# Or an easier way to understand what that line is doing:
result = "[" + ", ".join(a) + "]"
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[hello, how, are, you]
```

Otherwise if you want to turn strings to variables you can use `eval` but I highly don't recommend it and it is probably not what you want.